# Name of an elvish/fairy book series with a blondish girl in feathered armor on the cover?

Tags: story-identification, books, elves

It was a book series that isn't super old, about an Elf King and the girl that falls in love with him. I'm pretty sure her armor on one of the later books is gold.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description of the cover, I think it might be the "Mage Winds" trilogy by Mercedes Lackey, consisting of the books *Winds of Fate, Winds of Change*, and *Winds of Fury*; set in her Valdemar universe. There is no Elf King, however, but a tribe of "Hawk Brothers" that are rather elvish.
[image]